# Error : Analytics Reporting API V4 has not been used in project

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to access my Analytics data from a JAVA code. But when the following code is run,

```java
package com.test.googleapi;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.AnalyticsReporting;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.DateRange;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.Dimension;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.GetReportsRequest;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.GetReportsResponse;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.Metric;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.ReportRequest;

public class AnalyticsApiTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
                .fromStream(new FileInputStream(new File("assets/client-secrets/service-account-key.json")))
                .createScoped(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"));
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        AnalyticsReporting analyticsReporting = new AnalyticsReporting.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Test")
                .build();

        DateRange dateRange = new DateRange();
        dateRange.setStartDate("2015-06-15");
        dateRange.setEndDate("2015-06-30");

        // Create the Metrics object.
        Metric sessions = new Metric()
            .setExpression("ga:sessions")
            .setAlias("sessions");

        //Create the Dimensions object.
        Dimension browser = new Dimension()
            .setName("ga:browser");

        // Create the ReportRequest object.
        ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest()
            .setViewId("XXXX")
            .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
            .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(browser))
            .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(sessions));

        ArrayList<ReportRequest> requests = new ArrayList<ReportRequest>();
        requests.add(request);

        // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
        GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest()
            .setReportRequests(requests);

        // Call the batchGet method.
        GetReportsResponse response = analyticsReporting.reports().batchGet(getReport).execute();

    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Analytics Reporting API V4 has not been used in project analytics-test-1279 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/overview?project=analytics-test-1279 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Analytics Reporting API V4 has not been used in project analytics-test-1279 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/overview?project=analytics-test-1279 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.test.googleapi.AnalyticsApiTest.main(AnalyticsApiTest.java:73)
```

I have already setup a Service Account Key in the `analytics-test-1279` project. The Analytics API is also enabled.

[image: The Analytics API is enabled]

I could not figure out what exactly is the problem here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the error message, you need to enable the [Analytics Reporting API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/overview). They handily provided you with a direct link in the error to the same page.

From your screenshot you have enabled the [Analytics API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics/overview). Which contains the [Management API V3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) and the old [Core Reporting API V3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/).

With the release of [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) you need to enable the completly new API. The good news is that [authorize](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization) still uses the same scopes so there will be no need for your users to re-authorize your application.

Comment: Thanks, I had to enter the `Analytics` term into the search box before I got the `Analytics Reporting API V4`. Enabled it and then this problem has been resolved. Also had to add the service account email to the Analytics user management for accessing the data.